# Multiple namespaces in gSoap

Tags: c++, namespaces, gsoap

I have three web services. Client, Server and another Server. The first server acts as client to second server. Now i have two services that are being run on the same machine. These are seperate services, but one uses the other. But when i use both services, the namespace problem occurs.

```
error: redefinition of 'Namespace namespaces []'
```

How to resolve this namepsace problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by combining all webservices in one i.e
        wsdl2h -0 Service.h service1.wsdl service2.wsdl

and then 
        soapcpp2 -j Service.h

Now namespace error disappeared.